# Detect if a coroutine needs the asyncio loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm writing code that will wait on user-supplied coroutines using Twisted. In a simpler case all I need is to use [`defer.ensureDeferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.ensureDeferred.html) to turn a coroutine into a Deferred. But if a coroutine uses e.g. `asyncio.sleep()` I need to use `asyncio.ensure_future` to wrap it into an asyncio Task that will run in the asyncio loop and this needs `AsyncioSelectorReactor`. I want to support the first case even if `AsyncioSelectorReactor` is not used and so I don't want to call `asyncio.ensure_future` on all coroutines. The only way to do this that I can think of is somehow detecting if the coroutine needs asyncio, is that possible to do? Or, maybe, there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to call `asyncio.ensure_future` on all coroutines?

Comment: @kmaork "I want to support the first case even if AsyncioSelectorReactor is not used".

Comment: Have you considered allowing the user to supply a flag to the api for asyncio usage?

Comment: @stacksonstacks yes, and the user code will silently break unless the flag is passed, which is the main reason for this question

Answer (score 1):

It might help to check if asyncio is referenced inside the coroutine. Consider these examples:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    pass

async def test2():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

del asyncio
async def test3():
    import asyncio
```

Using `inspect.getclosurevars`, you can check for the presence of asyncio:

```py
assert 'asyncio' not in inspect.getclosurevars(test1).globals or inspect.getclosurevars(test2).globals

assert 'asyncio' in inspect.getclosurevars(test2).globals

assert 'asyncio' in inspect.getclosurevars(test3).unbound
```

Of course, this is would give a false positive when the user's coroutine imports something from asyncio that doesn't use the loop, such as exceptions or constants, or when the user code doesn't use the imported coroutines.